# How do you iterate through two items in a model and display on site using Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a models.py with the following fields:

```
class ChatStream(models.Model):
    bot = models.TextField()
    user = models.TextField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I'd like on a website to iterate through "bot" and "user" one at a time, so the site would hypothetically display something like:

bot: hello! 
user: what's up? 
bot: I'm good 
user: What's your name 
bot: bot is my name

.... etc. this would keep going...

So in my views.py I have

```
def displayDict(request):
    m = ChatStream.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'chatStream.html',
    {"chat": m})
 

def send(request):
    message = request.POST.get('userMessage', False)
    ip = visitor_ip_address(request)
    response = routes(message, ip)
    print(ip, "user sent:", message, "bot response:", response)
    chatItem = ChatStream(bot=response, user=message, name=ip)
    chatItem.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/chat/')
```

Then in my template, chat.html I have

```
{% block chatStream %} {% endblock %}
```

And chatStream.html (this is where the error is happening I believe... how do you iterate through two items in the model so they appear one after the other on the html file?)

```
{% extends 'chat.html' %}

{% block chatStream %}
{% for a in bot%}
{% for b in user%}
    <p>
        <b>bot:</b> {{a}} <br>
        <b>user:</b> {{b}} <br>
    </p>
{% endfor %}

<form action="/send/" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="userMessage">
    <input type="submit" value="Send to smallest_steps bot">
</form> 

{% endblock  %}
```

But this does not work -- no text from the model is displayed on the site. I am not understanding how to iterate through two items within the model at once inside of the `chatStream.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot going on here, lets try to break it down:

First, you need to pass context variables to your templates if you want to render them using the (jinja-like) Django template rendering system.

Your view function for rendering the template would look like this:

**views.py**

```py
def render_chat_page(request):

    # do some logic:
    ...

    # pack the context variables:
    context = {
        'some_key' : 'some_value',
        'chat_streams' : ChatStream.objects.all(),
        ...
    }

    return render(request, 'chat_page.html', context=context)
```

Ok, now that we've passed the context variables to the template, we can render html elements using the variables like so:

**template.html**

```html
<div> The value of "some_key" is: {{some_key}} </div>

{% for chat_stream in chat_streams %}
<div> user says: {{chat_stream.user}}</div>
<div> bot says: {{chat_stream.bot}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This will render the user and bot messages for each `ChatStream` object. However my hunch is that this is not entirely what you're after, instead you may want something more dynamic.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response. it worked! @Daniel

Answer (score 1):

In your displayDict view you're passing a QuerySet to the context. So, you need to loop over the QuerySet in your template.

```
{% extends 'chat.html' %}

{% block chatStream %}
{% for item in chat %}
    <p>
        <b>bot:</b> {{item.bot}} <br>
        <b>user:</b> {{item.user}} <br>
    </p>
{% endfor %}

<form action="/send/" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="userMessage">
    <input type="submit" value="Send to smallest_steps bot">
</form> 

{% endblock  %}
```

Comment: Thank you -- this was helpful and it worked!